# Android Mediaplayer: play multiple sounds

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

In my app, I have to play many sounds (mp3 files downloaded and stored on SD Card) one after the other.
So I used a basic MediaPlayer and I set setOnCompletionListener method to continue playing next media file:

```
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(PATH + Constants.Medias.PATH + SLASH + (pref + 1) + SLASH + AppUtils.format(suffix + 1) + AppUtils.format(currentMediaFile));
```

My big problem is that there is GAP when switching from a file to the next one... It make a strange noise that disturbs users.
Have you any idea how to play these files as if they are "one track" (continuously).

Answer (score 3):

You can try to create **two instances** of `MediaPlayer` (let's call them *M1* and *M2*).

- *M1* starts to play the first file (*F1*)
- while *M1* is playing, *M2* starts preparing for *F2* (only`prepare()` is called)
- when *M1* finish, its `OnCompletionListener` triggers M2 which starts to play
- continue inverting *M1* with *M2* until all files have been played.

If this doesn't work and you still hear noise try to use [**SoundPool**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) instead of `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: First solution didn't change the actual behavior.. I will try SoundPool may be I will get what I want!